# QSqlQuery forbid non-SELECT query

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I'm looking for a way to forbid non-SELECT query for a `QSqlQuery` object.

I know `QSqlQuery::isSelect` is only effective after `QSqlQuery::exec` (damage
already done here).

So, is there any way to do that or I have to verify the `query string` explicitly.

Thanks.

Comment: In general this is something you'd do through database permissions rather than through a database API.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I'm using SQLITE. And worse thing is that I'm expecting it to be Universal SQL solution. Can you sir please
provide me a complex SQL Query that would break through Regular-Expressions filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, the `QSqlQuery::isSelect` function works well even before running the `QSqlQuery::exec` command. But only when the object is initialized with the query. i.e:

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM someTable");
qDebug() << query.isSelect(); //Outputs True
```

OR

```
QString queryString = "SELECT * FROM someTable";
QSqlQuery query(queryString);
qDebug() << query.isSelect(); //Outputs True
```

If you are using the prepare function and passing the query string to it, then you will have to verify the query string yourself. i.e;

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT * FROM someTable");
qDebug() << query.isSelect(); //Outputs False
```

If you really want to avoid manual verification of the query string, you will have to avoid using `QSqlQuery::prepare` and `QSqlQuery::bindValue` functions and instead create the query yourself and initialize the `QSqlQuery` object with the `QString` you create.

Comment: Stupid me. Prepared-Statements are not complete statements for QSqlQuery to tell their types.
Anyway.. Thanks a lot.